# Several substitutions in perl

Tags: perl

How can I do two replacements with Perl?

I use the following code. I use twice s to replace...I would like all in less lines...

```
        (my $newName = $grib) =~ s/:00:00.grb//;
        rename $grib, $newName;

        (my $newName1 = $newName)  =~ s/d01/d02/g;
        rename $newName, $newName1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested:

```
(my $newName = $grib) =~ s/:00:00.grb//; rename $grib, $newName; (my $newName1 = $newName)  =~ s/d01/d02/g; rename $newName, $newName1;
```

But that's dumb. There's also no reason to stuff everything in one line. Instead, work on producing quality readable code. For starters, stop renaming twice when once would do!

```
my $newName = $grib;
$newName =~ s/:00:00.grb//;
$newName =~ s/d01/d02/g;
rename($grib, $newName)
   or die("Can't rename \"$grib\" to \"$newName\": $!\n");
```

With 5.14+, this can be reduced to the following:

```
my $newName = $grib =~ s/:00:00.grb//r =~ s/d01/d02/gr;
rename($grib, $newName)
   or die("Can't rename \"$grib\" to \"$newName\": $!\n");
```